# Using ruby application in launchctl scripts

Tags: macos, ruby, libraries, launchctl

In OS X, I am trying to create a script invoked automatically by `launchctl`.

This script will invoke ruby application (`jabber-tee` and `terminal-notifier`) installed with `gem`.

Her is my python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/local/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/opt/local/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/opt/local/sbin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/sbin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/sbin"

f = open("reminder.txt")

for line in f:
    tuple = line.split()
    text = tuple[0]
    target = tuple[1]

    os.system('echo  Do not forget me plz! "' + text + '" | /usr/bin/jabber-tee --to ' + target + '@jabber.8d.com')
    os.system('/usr/bin/terminal-notifier -message "Reminded ' + target + '" -title "Reminded"')%
```

When I am executing the script I got the following error.

```
/usr/bin/jabber-tee:4:in `require': no such file to load -- jabber-tee/cli (LoadError)
    from /usr/bin/jabber-tee:4
/usr/bin/terminal-notifier:7:in `require': no such file to load -- terminal-notifier (LoadError)
    from /usr/bin/terminal-notifier:7
```

It looks like the `require` statement does not work with `launchctl` any more.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cannot directly manipulate env variable with a script executed by lauchctl.

I had to invoke the following command in a terminal

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```